# Single html file for add edit view or multiple files

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am developing a simple CRUD application and let us say that I have a employye form and user has options to add new employee or edit/view employee from database (simple crud forms). Is it better to have

a) one html file with a lot of logic in javascript

or

b) multiple html files with a lot of duplicated code but less logic in javascript

?

In the future forms may become more complicated (business process, some fields visible only for user with specific rights etc.). I am wondering what is the best solution.

It is a web applcation with AngularJS.

Comment: You'll likely have all your logic on the server side, usually javascript will do all your form validations.

Comment: You need to provide more context. For instance: (Is it a webapp? Does it connect to a server? Or it will only be used at localhost? or offline?)

Answer (score 0):

I have a vast experience of HTML/CRUD applications (both simple and complex), I suggest you to go with first option:

> a) one html file with a lot of logic in javascript

As more logic is better than duplicated code. Also as you mentioned that in future there is more work on the page is expected, so keep the logic on one page and avoid duplication. I hope it is better option. Best of luck...